# In Unity, trying to get Vector3 coordinates from an Array and set them to a new variable. What is the correct syntax?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, transform

I have a list of all spawned objects in the game. I'm trying to search through that list to find only objects that are tagged "Road Tag", get their transform position, and convert it to a new variable.

If I use

> Debug.Log(spawnedObjects[i].transform.position;

It actually prints out the x, y, z coordinates fine. But I don't know how to assign them to a new Vector3 variable. The syntax for arrays seems to be different.

I have tried:

```
roadCoordinates[i] = new Vector3(spawnedObjects[i].transform.position.x, spawnedObjects[i].transform.position.y, spawnedObjects[i].transform.position.z);
```

and

```
roadCoordinates[i] = spawnedObjects[i].transform.position;

public static Vector3[] roadCoordinates;    


public static void FindSpawnedRoads()
{
    loopCount = spawnedObjects.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
    {
        if (spawnedObjects[i].tag == "Road Tag")
        {
            //This prints perfectly
            Debug.Log(spawnedObjects[i].transform.position);


            //This gives me NullReferenceException
            roadCoordinates[i] = new Vector3(spawnedObjects[i].transform.position.x, spawnedObjects[i].transform.position.y, spawnedObjects[i].transform.position.z);

            Debug.Log(roadCoordinates[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

I want the variable to be set to the Vector3 coordinates of `roadCoordinates[i]`.

I instead get `NullReferenceException`. Unless I print `SpawnedObjects` in which it prints the coordinates like I want.

Comment: How did you initialize or did you initialize `roadCoordinates` array?

Comment: Sorry, new to C#. I don't know what initialize means but I can tell you the three times the variable is used are all shown above.

Comment: From your questions below answers given and your comment about being new to C#, it seems you're missing some programming fundamentals like types and memory. Perhaps you should read up on these and ask directed questions in a separate question here on SO?

Comment: Yeah I'm definitely missing a lot but it's only been 2 weeks. I learn more every day :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the `roadCoordinates` array otherwise you would get the `NullReferenceException` error. Other than that your logic is okay. You can solve this by adding this line after `loopCount` assignment:

`roadCoordinates = new Vector3[loopCount];`

What happens when you do not initialize your array is you create a variable named `roadCoordinates` but there is no memory allocated or referenced for this variable. Therefore, it does not point to anything in the memory and when you try to use it it says i can't reference to any memory block.

As you mentioned in your question that you have a list of all spawned object you can also store these points in a List then you do not have to allocate any memory, you can just add elements to the list.

`List<Vector3> roadCoordinates = new List<Vector3>()`

Then you can add elements using `roadCoordinates.Add(spawnedObjects[i].transform.position)`

If you need to store the indexes of spawned object that has a `Road Tag` you can use a `Dictionary`

`Dictionary<int, Vector3> roadCoordinates = new Dictionary<int, Vector3>()`

Then you can add elements like `roadCoordinates.Add(i,spawnedObject[i].transform.position)`

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I would never have guessed to set it to assign it to loopCount. Why is that? Would using this do the same thing?


`roadCoordinates = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);`

Comment: No you can not to assign a vector to array of vectors. loopCount is the size of your array and actually is not a good practice because you actually do not know the size(how many elements have the tag) of your array. Therefore, a list is a better solution for this.

Comment: spawnedObjects is actually the list of all spawned game objects. Is there a better way to go about this? Why is it bad practice?

Comment: The solution is using a `List` instead of an `Array` of `roadCoordinates` because arrays have fixed size. You can only change the size by reallocating. You can not add or remove elements without reallocating. Consider a scenario where you saved 20 spots for a party but you do not know how many will attend.  Then lets say 5 people showed up, 15 spots are wasted or 30 people showed up then you do not have enough space or food/drinks for everyone.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Hmm. Well spawnedObjects is actually a list like I said. How would I call them if not using an array?

Comment: :) I have been telling you. You should use a `list`. I mentioned that in my answer. `SpawnedObjects` and `roadCoordinates` both should be a `list`. You can see how to do that from my answer.

Comment: Haha yeah sorry it's a lot to take in. I understand how to make a list and add things to it. What I don't get is how to use that list to manipulate it.

For example, I'm looking for all of their coordinates so that I can instantiate an object next to them.

I assume I make a list and use a For Each statement?

Comment: yes exactly you have to make a list, add items to it then traverse it with foreach

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use array.push() (see: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Array.Push.html) instead of writing 'roadCoordinates[i]', as this array is still empty. By using 'push', you add the new position/3D vector to the end of the array, which also works if the array is still empty. I hope this helps you out!

PS: if you first initialize the array to be of a certain length as suggested by the other answer, you will have a lot of empty array items as not every item in your loop is a 'Road tag'.

Comment: "Note: This is javascript only. C# does not use this feature". Quoted from the link

Comment: Of course you are right about that... Totally forgot about that. Then, the solution is to use a List, where you can run .Add().

Comment: Just saw your edit. Is there anything better to assign it to?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Also, you really don't need to add a dictionary. Just see my new reply on the root of this Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lists is better in this case, because we do not know from the start how many objects we are going to have.

```
List<Vector3> roadCoordinates = new List<Vector3>();

...

roadCoordinates.Add(new Vector3(...));
```

[Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/lists-and-dictionaries) is the tutorial about lists.

Comment: spawnedObjects are the list. This function searches through the list to see which objects are roads and then finds their transform.

I suppose I should change it to a dictionary and keep both their name and their transform though. Which do you think is less resource intensive for a mobile video game?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Alexander suggests, using Lists is the way to go. You don't need to use a dictionary as you already know that the roadCoordinates List will only contain items of tag 'Road Tag'.

```
public static List<Vector3> roadCoordinates = new List<Vector3>();

public static void FindSpawnedRoads()
{
    loopCount = spawnedObjects.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
    {
        if (spawnedObjects[i].tag == "Road Tag")
        {
            roadCoordinates.Add(new Vector3(spawnedObjects[i].transform.position.x, spawnedObjects[i].transform.position.y, spawnedObjects[i].transform.position.z));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Edit: Let me make this more readable. Hold on

Hey! I'm trying to figure out how I would do it with a foreach loop but the syntax doesn't seem to be right. Do you know what I have wrong here? It says I need to have an identifier but I have one (GameObject, right?)


    `public static void FindSpawnedRoadsForEach()
    {
        foreach(spawnedObjects.tag = "Road Tag" in spawnedObjects)
        {
            Debug.Log(spawnedObjects);
        }
    }`